# Handle Plaintext Passwords... Safely

Tags: php, security, passwords, backend

I'm working on a website that outputs data from Website B concisely and all in one view, quicker than it would take to log in and find all of it on Website B manually.

It needs to be useable by any user. Currently it works, but requires the user to log into my website with the credentials from Website B. Website B has no API and this is the only way I could think of doing it. Obviously, this is not ideal because the username and password is sent in plaintext over a get request to a php script I have on my site and does some web scraping. I also have the passwords optionally stored in user cookies (in plaintext) in order to be able to keep the user logged in.

I don't personally store them for myself, but any developer could change their backend to store passwords in plain text if they had malicious intent. Since I don't have malicious intent and it comes down to if the users trust the website, I'm more concerned with attackers potentially grabbing those passwords from user cookies or from the requests.

I've thought about hashing or encryption, but both would require for it to be possible to turn them back into plaintext passwords easily (allowing any attacker to find it just as easily as my system) so they can be entered into Website B for webscraping.

It's a dilemma and I honestly can't think of any better solution. Is there anything to be done that would make this at least a little more secure?

Comment: You should never use GET requests for sending sensitive information, such as login data.

Comment: Hashing is one way so that really isn't an option. Encryption on the other hand could be an option, you'd just need to store the key somewhere "relatively" safe on your server (out of the web root at the very least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't do this safely:

- Users will need to trust you with their credentials for logging into the remote website, which most won't. What you are doing is essentially the same as phishing. How do I, as an end user, know what you are doing with my credentials?
- You will be held responsible if and when a breach happens to your servers and all of the credentials are leaked, or code is injected into your script which sends the login information to a hacker's database. Encryption adds a small layer of security, but the private key will need to be accessible to the application in plain text as well as the login data when the user first logs in without the need for the private key.
- Instead of using an API, you are scraping the other website, which means that any small change in the HTML could break your site.
- The remote website could inject code into YOUR website.
- The remote website will log many logins for many users to your server's IP and may flag you and/or your users' accounts for suspicious activity.
- Your server essentially becomes a proxy server for logging in, which means login failures will also be registered to your server's IP. This could, again, get you and your users flagged or blacklisted, and also opens up the possibility of using your server to brute force logins to the remote server.
- If the remote server ever implements multi-factor authentication, this adds a layer of complexity, and if it uses Webauthn (e.g. U2F), it will be impossible for the users to log in through your server.

This is exactly why APIs exist. If one doesn't exist, contact the remote website and try to convince them why it is important that they have one. Offer to code it if it is really important to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.

I think the best course of action for me right now would be to contact them and request and API. Unfortunately, while I do have the capability to code my own API for them if desired, I'm quite young in comparison and I doubt they'd even take me seriously. Thank you though!